# Polymorphism in service providers laravel 5

Tags: laravel, service, polymorphism

Can we implement polymorphism in service provider.

I have this code in service provider

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\User\UserInterface', 'App\Repositories\User\UserRepository');
}
```

and in my UserController constructor

```
public function __construct( UserInterface $user){

    $this->user = $user;
}
```

So far the code works fine but I need to use also AdminRepository and I think in the register it is coupled in UserRepository. What would I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container#contextual-binding)

```
$this->app->when(AdminController::class)
          ->needs(UserInterface::class)
          ->give(AdminRepository::class);

$this->app->when(UserController::class)
          ->needs(UserInterface::class)
          ->give(UserRepository::class);
```